# How to ask meta-programming on Stack Overflow without being moderated?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm looking for thoughtful tips on asking [meta-programming questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/why-do-programers-help-each-other-without-pay-closed) on stackoverflow without getting sent to meta stackoverflow.

It seems to me that meta-programming != meta stackoverflow

Comment: Why don't you tell us what the question you want to ask is?

Comment: If you're not talking about Stack Overflow, then you really should not have your question shunted here just because it contains the word "meta".

Comment: A meta-programming question is not the same as a meta-question. Can you rephrase please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestion: avoid even using the word "stackoverflow" in your question. I've noticed that people can sometimes have a knee-jerk reaction to seeing the site mentioned, thinking that it needs to be on MetaSO because you are discussing/referencing SO.

I'm kind of on the fence about your [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/why-do-programers-help-each-other-without-pay-closed). You were speaking more *generally* about sites *like* SO, but not *specifically* SO. For that reason, it *probably* doesn't belong on MetaSO. However, I also feel like the connection to programming was a bit tenuous, and the question somewhat subjective and discussion-oriented. For those reasons, I don't think it was a very good fit for SO either. I would probably suggest another forum entirely.

Comment: Good answer and I agree with you on all aspects, except that I think it was good enough or at least interesting enough to bend the roles a little bit.

Comment: @P-A: Thanks. Admittedly, I take a harder-line stance on what constitutes an "appropriate" SO topic. I tend not to favor many *programmer-related* questions, but maybe that's just because I've seen too many questions like "Should I get my CS degree?" or "(*Insert career history*)... What should I do?" ;)

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of StackOverflow has been muddied somewhat over time, but the original purpose was to be a place for technical questions and answers.

Many people have used it to try talking about the environmental factors related to working in an office, or programming interviews, or team dynamics, however those would be fitting for a 'programming forum' where programmers are meant to congregate and chat. However, StackOverflow is not meant for that. It is meant to be an engine for programmers to get answers to their technical difficulties. The community environment was cultivated in order to have people want to be helpful to one another, it was not meant to detract from the purpose of the site.

The fact of the matter is that your question "Why do programmers help each other" is not actually a technical question related to programming. The question is deeply philosophical and psychological, and bears only passing reference to programming. An equally valid (read: invalid) question would be "Why are lawyers so much less inclined to help each other than programmers?" It bears the same reference to programming, but it is more a question about people and attitudes than about programming. Such questions are not appropriate for any of S[O|F|U].

It can be rephrased to be relevant on metaStackOverflow.

"What drives the incentive to participate in S[O|F|U]?" would be a more valid question, because (especially if you are thinking about getting your own stackExchange site) this is the correct environment to pose those queries. Keep in mind, that question is still specific to why people would participate in *these* sites, not why "programmers in general" are or are not "helpful".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your question was programming related, and would have voted to close.  It doesn't belong here either.  Probably needs to be on one of the social networking sites (which this isn't).

**meta-programming <> StackOverflow**

Comment: Good, to-the-point answer. IMHO, questions like that require a Magic 8-Ball-equipped site to be answered effectively...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any more example questions? If it programming, it will stay on SO. If it is about SO or any of the other sites/features/how it works, then it will go to meta.stackoverflow. As long as your question is clear about it's intent, it will go/stay to the appropriate site.

Here are the FAQ's for both sites just as reminder of the goals of each site:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq
- https://stackoverflow.com/faq

That question you refer to is wiki type material if it was going to stay open. I think it should have stayed on SO as a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I think [your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/why-do-programers-help-each-other-without-pay-closed) was a valid question for Stack Overflow. It should have been wiki, and it was likely a dupe, but it definitely was valid.

Comment: (-1) It is not valid for StackOverflow. It is not about programming. It is about people helping each other, which can be done in any profession.

Comment: @devinb: Then why do you think it should be on meta?

Comment: Because all the StackExchange sites are based on the premise that people will help each other for free. So his question is ultimately about the business model. We the community are the clients/users of the sites, and that questions is about understanding your users better.

Comment: Point taken, although I still disagree.